# Friedrichs's inequality?

Tags: inequality, sobolev-spaces

Friedrichs's second inequality is stated as follows(see [www.win.tue.nl/~drenth/Phd/friedrichs.ps](http://www.win.tue.nl/~drenth/Phd/friedrichs.ps)):
For all $\mathbf{u} \in H^1(\Omega)^2$ satisfying either $\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{u} = 0$ or $\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{0}$ on $\partial\Omega$ where $\Omega$ is a simply connected domain, then 
$$
\|\mathbf{u}\|_1 \le C_1 (\|\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}\|_0 + \|\nabla\times\mathbf{u}\|_0).
$$
My question is that if the boundary condition is satisfied only on the nonempty part of $\partial\Omega$, i.e., either $\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{u} = 0$ or $\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{0}$ on $\emptyset \neq \Gamma \subset \partial\Omega$, does the inequality above hold?

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Thank [Stephen Montgomery-Smith](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/22016/stephen-montgomery-smith) very much for your response. ^_^

In paper [On the Validity of Friedrichs' Inequalities](http://mscand.dk/article.php?id=2705)，$\Omega$ is a bounded convex domain of $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d=2,3$. Then
$$
(1.4) \qquad \|\mathbf{u}\|_{1,\Omega} \le C(\|\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}\|_{0,\Omega} +\|\nabla\times\mathbf{u}\|_{0,\Omega})
$$
for all $\mathbf{u}\in\mathbf{H}_0(div;\Omega) \cap \mathbf{H}(curl;\Omega)$ or $\mathbf{u}\in\mathbf{H}(div;\Omega) \cap \mathbf{H}_0(curl;\Omega)$.

If $\mathbf{u}\in\mathbf{H}(div;\Omega) \cap \mathbf{H}(curl;\Omega)$ with two types of boundary conditions: $\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{u} = 0 \text{ on }\Gamma_1$ and $\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{0} \text{ on }\Gamma_2$, where $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2\neq\emptyset$, does the inequality (1.4) hold?

Comment: What do you mean by "non-empty" part?

Comment: Also, I have to admit that I have never heard of Friedrichs' inequality.  I looked it up and found this: http://www.mscand.dk/article.php?id=2705  There everything is stated for 2D, whereas by writing $H^1(\Omega)^3$, it implies you mean it in 3D.  But in 3D, a ball with a smaller ball removed from its interior is still simply connected.  But the Newtonian potential from a point inside the smaller ball - wouldn't that contradict the statement you wrote?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I refer to the paper:  [www.win.tue.nl/~drenth/Phd/friedrichs.ps](http://www.win.tue.nl/~drenth/Phd/friedrichs.ps). The results in this paper is also valid in 3d.‎ The nonempty part of $\partial\Omega$ means that the boundary condition $\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{n}=0$ or $\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{n}=\mathbf{0}$ is only valid on some nonempty sub-boundary $\Gamma \subset \partial\Omega$.

Comment: Crosspost: [mathoverflow.net/questions/150463/friedrichss-inequality](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/150463/friedrichss-inequality)

Comment: Crosspost: [scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10196/friedrichss-inequality](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10196/friedrichss-inequality)

Comment: OK, I'll think about it.  It may take me a while.  However, in 3D the condition "simply connected" is not sufficient, and that is a mistake in the paper, I think.  They need the 2nd cohomology group of $\Omega$ to be trivial.

Comment: It would have been better Engish to say "a nonempty part" rather than "the nonempty part."  Then I would have understood right away.  But I know some languages don't distinguish between the definite and indefinite article, so I do understand the mistake.  (And since English is my first language, I am not that good at it either :-).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $\Omega = \{ x \in \mathbb R^2 : \frac12 < |x| < 1, x_1 > 0\}$, and let $u(x) = \frac x{|x|^2}$.  Then $\nabla\cdot u = 0$ and $\nabla \times u = 0$.  The condition $u \times n=0$ holds on the circular parts of the boundary, and the condition $u \cdot n=0$ holds on the straight parts of the boundary.  But clearly $\|u\|_1 \ne 0$.

Comment: Nice example +1. And this example can be naturally extended to a cylindrical shell w/o modifying anything.