# The second Friedrichs' inequalities?

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, potential-theory

In paper [On the Validity of Friedrichs' Inequalities](http://mscand.dk/article.php?id=2705)，$\Omega$ is a bounded convex domain of $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d=2,3$. Then
$$
\tag{1}\qquad \|\mathbf{u}\|_{1,\Omega} \le C\Big(\|\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}\|_{0,\Omega} +\|\nabla\times\mathbf{u}\|_{0,\Omega}\Big)
$$
for all $\mathbf{u}\in\mathbf{H}_0(\operatorname{div};\Omega) \cap \mathbf{H}(\operatorname{curl};\Omega)$ or $\mathbf{u}\in\mathbf{H}(\operatorname{div};\Omega) \cap \mathbf{H}_0(\operatorname{curl};\Omega)$.

If $\mathbf{u}\in\mathbf{H}(\operatorname{div};\Omega) \cap \mathbf{H}(\operatorname{curl};\Omega)$ with mixed boundary conditions: 
$$\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{u} = 0 \text{ on }\Gamma_1, \quad \text{ and }\quad \mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{0} \text{ on }\Gamma_2, $$ 
where $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2\neq\emptyset$, $\Gamma_1\cap \Gamma_2 = \emptyset$, and $\overline{\Gamma}_1\cup \overline{\Gamma}_2 = \partial \Omega$. Does the inequality $(1)$ hold?

Comment: I think this answers works for this question as well: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587677/friedrichss-inequality/588282#588282

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no.

A pretty nice counter-example has been given by Stephen in this question: [Friedrichs's inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587677/friedrichss-inequality/588282)

---

Backstory 1: 
$\mathbf{H}_0(\operatorname{div};\Omega) \cap \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{curl};\Omega)$ and $\mathbf{H}(\operatorname{div};\Omega) \cap \mathbf{H}_{0}(\mathbf{curl};\Omega)$ are *compactly* embedded in $\mathbf{L}^2(\Omega)$. However, if the homogeneous boundary condition is only on part of the boundary,  this compact embedding result is not true as of my knowledge. Rellich–Kondrachov compactness argument is used to prove the Poincaré-Friedrichs type inequality.

For the estimate, please refer to *Vector potentials in three-dimensional non-smooth domains* by Cherif Amrouche, Christine Bernardi, Monique Dauge and Vivette Girault.

Backstory 2:
The function satisfies the boundary condition can be constructed implicitly using the following problem:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
-\Delta w = 0 & \text{ in }\Omega,
\\
w = 1 & \text{ on }\Gamma_2,
\\
\frac{\partial w}{\partial n} = 0& \text{ on }\Gamma_1.
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
Let the $\mathbf{u} = \nabla w$, we can see that this vector potential satisfies:
$$
\nabla\times \mathbf{u} = 0
\text{ and }
\nabla\cdot \mathbf{u} = 0,
\\
\mathbf{n}\times \mathbf{u}\big|_{\Gamma_2} = 0,\text{ and }
\mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{u}\big|_{\Gamma_1} = 0.
$$
Yet $\mathbf{u}$ itself is totally non-trivial.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help! Best regards!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I think it's worth to improve the previous answer with some remarks for the benefit of future readers.

---

- The space $\{ \mathbf u \in \mathbf{H}(\operatorname{\textbf{curl}}; \Omega) \cap H(\operatorname{\textbf{div}};\Omega) : \mathbf
  u \cdot \mathbf n |_{\Gamma_1} = 0, \ \mathbf u \times \mathbf n |_{\Gamma_2} = \mathbf 0 \}$ *is* in fact compactly embedded into $\mathbf L^2(\Omega)$ if $\Omega$ is merely weak Lipschitz (see reference $[1]$). On the other hand, it is not embedded into $\mathbf{H}^1(\Omega)$.
- One *can* thus obtain a Poincaré-Friedrichs inequality similar to $(1)$ even with mixed boundary conditions, **but** with the $\| \cdot \|_{0,\Omega}$ norm of the LHS and imposing an orthogonality condition with respect to a space of so-called "Dirichlet-Neumann" harmonic fields - vectors with zero curl and divergence and suitable null normal/tangential traces -. You may look at [$1$, Thm. 5.1].  Interestingly enough, the additional requirement prevents the above counterexample.

---

Reference:

$[1]$ Sebastian Bauer, Dirk Pauly and Michael Schomburg. "The Maxwell compactness property in bounded weak Lipschitz domains with mixed boundary conditions." SIAM Journal on Mathematical Analysis 48.4 (2016): 2912-2943.

Comment: Nice answer, Gac! Thank you very much! I checked the paper you mentioned, but it seems that the orthogonality is defined in L2, then how can one check whether the orthogonality condition is satisfied?